# Oracle Coherence CohQL - limit results

Tags: oracle-coherence

Is there a way to limit results of CohQL query?

My Coherence cache contains million records and it would be very useful to just limit the number of records if I just want to see how a specific entry looks like. for e.g. something like

```
select top 10 key() from cache
```

I don't find any such option in CohQL docs.

Comment: It's not possible with cohql. You can write your own java app and use a LimitFilter....

Answer (score 0):

ok, so its quite simple...
do `select top 10 * from <cache-name>`

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work for me either, for some cache...not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not possible using CohQL but this can be achieved using [LimitFilter](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/util/filter/LimitFilter.html) in Java. Based on your question, you are expecting `top` results without specifying any [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245322/how-does-select-top-works-when-no-order-by-is-specified).

Here is an example on how to use LimitFilter from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15723/api_querycache.htm#CDEBGJHI) with `order by Age desc`. If you want your results in random order, you will have to implement the [EntryFilter](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/util/filter/EntryFilter.html) interface to return random entry and use it instead of `GreaterEqualsFilter` in the example.