# Smarter SQL UPDATE between two tables (bill and bill rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two SQL tables:

```
Bills (BillId, Folio, Date, ProductId)
BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId, Lot, Quantity, Price)
```

- `ProductId` is optional in `Bills`
- `ProductId` is mandatory in `BillsRows`
- If all the rows of a bill have the same `ProductId` then the bill will have that `ProductId`
- If there are mixed `ProductId` within a bill, then the bill will have `ProductId = NULL`

Visual example:
[image: Bills with rows]

I have created the following **SQL UPDATE** but I'm not sure it is efficient:

```
update Bills
set ProductId = (
    select top 1 ProductId
    from BillsRows
    group by ProductId, BillId
    having count(*) = (select count(*) from BillsRows where BillId = Bills.BillId)
    and BillId = Bills.BillId
)
```

The fact that I'm counting all the rows is what makes me think it is not quite efficient.

**Is there any smarter alternative than this?**

**Update: added two samples**

**Sample 1: *Bill should be updated to ProductId=1 because all of the rows have ProductId=1***

```
insert into Bills (BillId, Folio, Date, ProductId) values (1, 324, '2022-04-14', null)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (1, 1, 1111)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (2, 1, 1111)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (3, 1, 1111)
```

**Sample 2: *Bill should be updated to ProductId=NULL because it has different products***

```
insert into Bills (BillId, Folio, Date, ProductId) values (2, 325, '2022-04-14', null)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (4, 2, 1111)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (5, 2, 2222)
insert into BillsRows (BillRowId, BillId, ProductId) values (6, 2, 3333)
```

Comment: That `UPDATE` is flawed. It isn't correlated (though oddly the subquery within the subquery is), it has a `GROUP BY` (which will result in multiple rows) and then you have a `TOP 1` with no `ORDER BY` meaning that you are going to assign an *arbitrary* value to *every* row in `Bills`. It is very unlikely to do what you think it does, or what you want it to do.

Comment: It works fine @Larnu meaning that it does what I presented in the picture.

Comment: I doubt that, @sports . If it is, it's more blind luck.

Comment: You said this: "it has a GROUP BY (which will result in multiple rows)". The first "having" assures that the result will be exactly one row, not multiple rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245322/how-does-select-top-works-when-no-order-by-is-specified

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
update B
set B.ProductId =R.ProductID
from Bills B inner join
BillsRows R on R.BillID=B.BillID
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from BillsRows BR where BR.BillId = R.BillId 
    and B.ProductID<> BR.ProductId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query. It should be faster.

```
update Bills
set ProductId = (
    select max(ProductId)
    from BillsRows
    group by BillId
    having count(distinct ProductId) =1
    and BillId = Bills.BillId
)
```

Comment: Excellent and easy to read

Comment: Although i had to use `select top 1`

Comment: Thanks @sports. But since I have used max() top 1 should not be needed. Please try without it.

Comment: I tried with max as you suggested but it throws: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: hmmm sorry your answer is not working... i checked and it updated wrong :( it gave a value to those bills that have mixed products

Comment: Would you please share some sample data in text format or a db-fiddle link. So that, I can test for myself.

Comment: @sports my mistake. I should have removed ProductId from group by clause. Now please check.

Comment: Ok, i will add sample data

Comment: I can't use max(ProductId) if its not included in the group by, but actually the group-by isn't necessary, right?

Comment: You need ProductId for a BillId where all the ProductIds are same. So group by BillId should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this update might be more efficient than what I initially posted:

```
update Bills
set 
Bills.ProductId = (
    select 
        top 1 ProductId
    from BillsRows
    where BillsRows.BillId = Bills.BillId
)
where BillId in (
    select 
        BillsRowsGrouped.BillId
    from (
        select 
            BillsRows.BillId, 
            BillsRows.ProductId
        from BillsRows
        group by 
            BillsRows.BillId,
            BillsRows.ProductId
    ) as BillsRowsGrouped
    group by BillsRowsGrouped.BillId
    having count(*) = 1
)
```

If we read from inside to outside...

**First we have this**:

```
        select 
            BillsRows.BillId, 
            BillsRows.ProductId
        from BillsRows
        group by 
            BillsRows.BillId,
            BillsRows.ProductId
```

*(This returns a virtual table with two columns: `BillId` and `ProductId`)*

**Then, I group again, by `BillId`, and stick with those with `count(*) = 1`**

```
    select 
        BillsRowsGrouped.BillId
    from (...) as BillsRowsGrouped
    group by BillsRowsGrouped.BillId
    having count(*) = 1
```

**Finally, I update using the top 1 result from BillsRows and making sure BillId is in the previous query**:

```
update Bills
set 
Bills.ProductId = (
    select 
        top 1 ProductId
    from BillsRows
    where BillsRows.BillId = Bills.BillId
)
where BillId in (...)
```